# How can I use our data types in apache thrift

Tags: thrift

How can I do something like this with apache thrift.

```
typedef i64 long
typedef i32 int
service MyService {
          long multiply(1:int num1, 2:int num2),
          MyService getMyservice()
}
```

here I have defined a MyService and it is used inside of the MyService as the return type of getMyService. Is there a way to do something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use language-specific types in an IDL-file. Keep in mind that the IDL-file needs to be usable on other languages also, that don't necessarily know what a `long` or an `int` are. The above code is syntactically legal, but will for instance generate C++ files that do not compile, as `long` and `int` are names of types that are already built into the language.

Also, returning a service is not allowed, as it is basically just an interface. If you wanted to actually be able to return a service (including implementations of functions I presume), you would need some way to convert your code on one end, to some generic code that could run on all other platforms and all other languages. So while it would certainly be possible to do on two platforms that use the same language and environment, it gets very non-trivial as soon as any platform variety comes into the picture.

Comment: yeah, but i think here it is legal because I have defined a type as int and long. Here the problem is, I am retuning the same data type MyService in getMyService method. How can I do something like that.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question, but even though the syntax in the IDL-file is legal, the Thrift compiler does not have any way to map your your typedef'ed `int` and `long` to the actual `int` and `long` in your language. On C++, it creates the line `typedef int32_t int;` in the generated file, which does not compile.

Comment: Can you also give me an idea for the second question. How can i return an object with the type of MyService

Comment: Updated the answer - hope it's enough?

Comment: Hi i don't know whether i am asking correct or not i am not familiar with thrift,if i am writing my site ruby on rails and want use the services in Java projects like apache nutch,lucene and hadoop,do i have the scope for implementing that?